# Sitecore Dictionary Labels in SXA Rendering Variants?

Tags: sxa

How do I make use of Sitecore Dictionary Labels in SXA Rendering Variants?
I want the CTA Text to come from Dictionary. It will have two texts namely "View More" and "View Less" in 3 languages.

Comment: Take a look here: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/04/sitecore-sxa-custom-rendering-variant-translation.html

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no ootb solution to do this. We had a similar issue and decided to write our own variant definition to accommodate this. Our idea was to have a variant similar to `Text` variant, but instead of the actual text you could give the key of the dictionary.

My [blog post](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/04/sitecore-sxa-custom-rendering-variant-translation.html) on the topic explains in detail how to create this custom variant. In short, you need to:

- create a template for the variant (and set insert options for it)
- create a model that matches the template
- create a parse processor (inherit `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.ParseVariantFields.ParseVariantFieldProcessor`) to create a model from the variant item
- create a render processor (inherit `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderRenderingVariantFieldProcessor`) that does the actual rendering
- add both processors to the config

Note: do set the SupportedTemplateID in the parse processor and check the model in the render processor as all variants go through the same pipelines.