# Does SXA have OOTB support for Dictionary text stored at a per-site level

Tags: sxa, dictionary

Does SXA have out of the box support (i.e. some API method to call) for Dictionary text stored at a per-site level? If so, how is this enabled?

Comment: You can use the [OOTB Sitecore Dictionary](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-asp-net-cms-6-6-features-dictionary-domains), and set the `dictionaryDomain` attribute on the site node entry (and use domain fallback if you want). Worth bearing in [mind for variants](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/sitecore-dictionary-labels-in-sxa-rendering-variants).

Comment: This was added ootb in 9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sitecore 9.3 when you create a new site you will find a Dictionary node in it. This works like the ootb Sitecore dictionary and includes fallback to more generic dictionaries (you can set which ones).

[image]

Reading values from this dictionary can be done with Scriban with the `sc_translate` function. More info here: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/11/sitecore-sxa-93-scriban.html

If you are not on 9.3, you could use the solution Kamruz mentioned or go custom.. For an older project I created a custom variant that could handle translations. Creating the variant can be found here: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/04/sitecore-sxa-custom-rendering-variant-translation.html. You do need to link this variant to a translation mechanism - in our case that was custom too, but out of scope for that blog post. You could link it to any code that can translate labels though.